# Slow ssh login on CentOS

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, openssh

I have a CentOS 6.8 installation on VMware, however, the ssh login process is very slow.

I tried to use `-v` option to diagnose the problem, and found that it stopped at the last line for a couple of seconds.

`OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.17.128 [192.168.17.128] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/theos/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/theos/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/theos/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/theos/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/theos/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/theos/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/theos/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/theos/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug1: Authenticating to 192.168.17.128:22 as 'drizzlex'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<3072<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:9FbIfP7k2QdKsR7iWic5+WehvIeI2C/v8UCNwQws9bs
debug1: Host '192.168.17.128' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/theos/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received`

Then it continued

`debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/theos/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.17.128 ([192.168.17.128]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
Last login: Sun Apr 16 11:02:29 2017 from 192.168.17.1`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: There are a few things that can help with that delay:  1) disable KEX and declare one 2) declare a cipher and prevent a cipher equalize to happen. 3) set your default key for that host in .ssh/config

Answer (score 3):

Slow SSH logins are often due to [UseDNS](http://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#UseDNS) being enabled in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (on the server side). Note that this option was enabled by default until [OpenSSH 6.8](https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-6.8).

Try setting `UseDNS no` instead. Make sure to restart `sshd` so the setting takes effect. You can also `kill -HUP <sshd_pid>` to reload the configuration.

Comment: I tried this, and it didn't work.